# Do anacron jobs accumulate?

Tags: cron

Let's say you set a script to run every week using anacron job, then you keep the machine turned
off for "N" weeks. My question is: will the script run "N" times when you turn it on, or just one
time and ignore the several times that it did not run?
(sorry my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

If a job is due to be run, it will run only once.